# C# XNA - any way to "refresh" game states?

Tags: c#, enums, xna

So I'm using `enum` for game states. When I am in the `game playing` state I can pause and return to the `main menu`. But if I click `Play game` and move to `game playing` again, everything is as I left it. I'm looking for a way to somehow "restart/refresh/flush" the `game playing` state. So if I go back to it I will have to start over.

Comment: sounds like you need to implement so 'Restart/ Continue/` functionality etc so if you have something you want or need to add in regards to the `enum` add it.. also show some code so we can see what your enum looks like

Comment: Just off the top of my head: what about possibly adding a NewGame state that would switch to Playing after init / setup is complete?

Answer (score 1):

You have some code now (one presumes) that initializes your game state when the program starts. You need to factor that code out (if necessary) so that it can also be called to initialize the game state any time you want. Such as when you are starting a new game, i.e. moving your game state to "game playing".

Indeed, most of the initialization code (i.e. everything except the stuff that doesn't need to be reinitialized on a new game), you'll probably want to run *only* then. Running it when you start up the program and then again later is redundant and will just slow boot times down.

Comment: You mean I should put it in `Initialize()`?

Comment: I don't know. I don't do XNA, so I don't know what "Initialize()" is or when it gets called. But, assuming that's a method that XNA calls automatically when you switch to the "game playing" state from the "main menu" state, yes...that sounds like a good place to put your initialization. :)

Comment: Peter's answer _"need to factor that code out"_ is generally correct, but **don't** put it in **[Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.initialize.aspx)** .  The reason is because XNA's **Game.Initialize()** is called only once and that is during startup.  See above link for more details.  You'll need to create a new method and invoke it from **[Game.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.update.aspx)** when appropriate

Answer (score 0):

My gameplay class have lists like "Enemies", "Explosions", "Bullets"... and inside Gampleay class i have Init sub that is executed when is state changed to "gameplay". It clears all and load level.

in pseudo code looks like this:

```
Class GamePlay
    Sub Init
       Enemies.Clear()
       Explosions.Clear()
       Bullets.Clear()
       Paralax.Clear()
       Stars.Clear()
       LoadLevel(lvl)
    End Sub

    Sub LoadLevel(lvl)
       Stars.Geneate(200)
       Paralax.Add(new Paralax(type, position, velocity))
    End Sub

    Sub Update
        if (mainship.fire) bullets.fire()
    End Sub

    Sub Draw
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Whilst a fine answer for initial game startup, it does not address the OP's desire of how to _"restart/refresh/flush"_ via a `state machine`